# Objective c stop animations of UIImageView on UINavigationController segue

Tags: objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

I have some strange animations when transitioning between views with `UINavigationController`. The images start with different frame properties and animate to the ones that i have set each time i segue with `UINavigationController`. I can't find anything to make that animation go away. Does it have something to do with `ViewWillAppear` implementation?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    LoadingView* loadingView;

    // adding a loading view
    loadingView = [self setViewLoading];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                              initWithTitle:@"≡"
                                              style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                              target:self.revealViewController
                                              action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:)];


    // pan gesture for side menu (Facebook style)
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Brands";

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

    self.menusDataArray = self.menusData[TAG_MENUS];

    // removing loading view.
    [self setViewNotLoading:loadingView];
}





- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    // if I don't do this, the swipe gesture for the Facebook stile side menu won't be recognised after pressing back on navigation controller bar
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your code??

Comment: I've added the code of the two methods. I really don't know what is happening. I just want the view to appear as is, without any fancy animations :). (My deployment target is ios 7.0; if it matters)

Comment: I think it has something to do with segues. the line causing the problem is [super viewWillAppear:animated]; . I've removed it and it doesn't do the animations anymore but the last selected row (the view is a table view) remains selected. I've also tried [super viewWillAppear:NO]; and the animations are still there. The funny part is that the app is running perfectly until a certain point, after which these random animations start to appear at each segue.

Comment: oh so now you need to deselect your last tablerows right??

Comment: That would be one part. Because, after that change, if i click on a row, the animations are starting again. I guess that this isn't a solution for my problem :). The animations look like all the UIViews are created with certain frame properties and animate to to the "desired" frame. Isn't there a way to globally stop all animations of views components during segues?

Comment: [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone]; Are you using this method??

Comment: solved it...i was modiffing the properties of uiview (activating animation) in a viewcontroller. :) .... thx for the help